# How to find duplicated Ruby methods with the same name but different code?

Tags: ruby, methods, grep, race-condition, code-duplication

The very large Ruby codebase I am working with has many instances of duplicated methods defined with the same name but some of its code is different (causing a large race condition problem). The eventual end goal is to reconcile the duplicates and have just one version of the same-named method. First I need to find all versions of a method that deviate from the "control" version of that method. Is there an optimal way to search and for and find all instances of duplicated same-named methods that deviate from one defined version?

The duplicated methods are spread out across hundreds of different files and contained in one class. These are essentially helper methods that should have been centralized in one file but instead have been duplicated and often altered, but keeping the same method name. Right now I just need a good way to locate all the instances where these methods have been duplicated and are different from what the method should be.

I think Rubocop only searches for duplicated method names which is only moderately helpful since it could find 237 methods with the same name but I don't know how many of those methods are deviations from my "control" method without manually looking and comparing.

Some examples of a method redefined in files across multiple subdirectories:

```
def get_field(field_name)
  return nil unless field = @global_vars.business.fields.find_by_identifier(field_name)
  field.value.present? ? field.value : nil
end

def get_field(field_name)
  @global_vars.business.fields.find_by_identifier(field_name).try(:value)
end

def get_field(field_name)
  return nil unless field @company.fields.find_by_identifier(field_name)
  field.value.present? ? field.value : nil
end

def get_field(field_name)
  @property.fields.find_by_identifier(field_name).try(:value)
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is quite a vague problem, especially since you mention "race conditions". Are the methods defined in different files? Different classes/modules? Why does the order in which files are loaded affect which method "takes precedence"? Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem? There are all sorts of things you *could* try, but I'm not sure what to suggest, with such little information to go on.

Comment: Hey @TomLord, the duplicated methods are spread out across hundreds of different files and contained in one class. These are essentially helper methods that should have been centralized in one file but instead have been duplicated over and over and often altered, but keeping the same method name. Right now with this question I just need a good way to locate all the instances where these methods have been duplicated and are different from what the method _should_ be. So it's more of a research and planning phase of dealing with a race condition.

Comment: 237 methods with the same name in the same Class? Many methods have the same name but different implementations for numerous reasons e.g. `Integer#+` and `String#+` should obviously differ, but I am not sure why you would have them redefined over and over in the same class.

Comment: Based on your above comment what you should do is write a module that contains the "control" method and then include it in the class and remove all the other references regardless of their implementation

Comment: You should clarify by editing your question, not trying to explain in comments.

Comment: Could you post an example of three truncated methods? It may be possible to compare the bytecode of each of the similarly named functions, but the success of that approach depends on how similar the 'correct' implementations are to each other. Alternatively, @engineersmnky is correct in that you should write a module with the correct implementation, and include it in every other class, and nuke each class-specific method

Comment: @Max I've added some examples of a method with different variations.

Comment: Do you have (or could you produce) a list of all modules (of which some are classes) that may contain instance methods of the same name in different files? Also, are you only interested in instance methods, as opposed to class/module methods?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I believe for the most part they are housed in one module and I think they are all instance methods.

Comment: @TomaNistor You said the issue is that "the same method is defined in **one class**, in **multiple files**". And yet, **your example does not show multiple files, and does not show a `class`**. Can you please make your example a bit clearer, so I know what we're dealing with here?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that what I've proposed probably won't work; more generally, that no solution that runs code in the files of interest is likely to work. For one, it would likely cause an exception to be raised almost immediately. For another, it could cause unwanted side effects (such as modifying a database). I therefore deleted my answer. I will, however,  offer another solution (in a separate answer) that I think has promise.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to execute each file of interest with additional code added on the fly to build a directory of methods and their locations. That clearly would not work, however, as exceptions could be expected to be raised almost immediately. Even if exceptions were avoided there would be no guarantee that that added code would be executed. In addition, there could be unintended adverse consequences of blinding running code.

I think the only reasonable approach would be to parse the files of interest. There may even be gems that do just that. It's certainly worth a search.

I have constructed a method that parses the files to build a hash containing the information desired. The main requirement for its use is that the files are formatted properly; specifically, the key words `class`, `module` and `def` must be indented the same number of spaces as their corresponding `end` keywords. It will therefore miss modules, classes and methods that are defined in-line, such as the following.

```
module M; end
class C; end
def im(n) 2*n end
def self.cm(n) 2*n end
```

If vertical alignment is a problem there certainly are gems that format code properly.

I chose a particular hash structure, but once that hash has been constructed it could be modified as desired. For example, I've adopted the hierarchy "instance methods->files->containers" ("containers" being modules, classes and top-level). One could easily modify that hash to change the hierarchy to, say, "container->module methods->files". Alternatively, one could enter the information into a database to maintain flexibility on how is used.

**Code**

The following regular expression is used to parse each line of each file of interest.

```
R = /
    \A                             # match beginning of string
    (?<indent>[ ]*)                # capture zero or more spaces, name 'indent' 
    (?:                            # begin non-capture group
      (?<type>class|module)        #   capture keyword 'class' or 'module', name 'type'
      [ ]+                         #   match one or more spaces
      (?<name>\p{Upper}\p{Alnum}*) #   capture an uppercase letter followed by
                                   #   >= alphanumeric chars, name 'name'
    |                              # or
      (?<type>def)                 #   capture keyword 'def', name 'type'
      [ ]+                         #   match one or more spaces
      (?<name>                     #   begin capture group named 'name'
        (?:self\.)?                #   optionally match 'self.'
        \p{Lower}\p{Alnum}*        #   match a lowercase letter followed by
                                   #   >= 0 zero alphanumeric chars, name 'name'
      )                            #   close capture group 'name'
    |                              # or
      (?<type>end)                 #   capture keyword 'end', name 'type'
      \b                           #   match a word break
    )                              # end non-capture group
    /x                             # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The method used for parsing follows.

```
def find_methods_by_name(files_of_interest)
  files_of_interest.each_with_object({ imethod: {}, cmethod: {} }) do |fname, h|
    stack = []
    File.readlines(fname).each do |line|
      m = line.match R
      next if m.nil?
      indent, type, name = m[:indent].size, m[:type], m[:name]
      case type
      when "module", "class"
        name = stack.any? ? [stack.last[:name], name].join('::') : name
        stack << { indent: indent, type: type, name: name }
      when "def"
        if name =~ /\Aself\./
          stack << { indent: indent, type: :cmethod, name: name[5..-1] }
        else
          stack << { indent: indent, type: :imethod, name: name }
        end
      when "end"
        next if stack.empty? || stack.last[:indent] != indent
        type, name = stack.pop.values_at(:type, :name)
        next if type == "module" or type == "class"
        ((h[type][name] ||= {})[fname] ||= []) << (stack.any? ?
          [stack.last[:type], stack.last[:name]].join(' ') : :main)
      end
    end
    raise StandardError, "stack = #{stack} after processing file '#{fname}'" if stack.any?
  end
end
```

**Example**

The files of interest might be, for example, all files in certain directories. In this example we have just two files.

```
files_of_interest = ['file1.rb', 'file2.rb']
```

Those files are as follows.

```
File.write('file1.rb',
<<_)
    def mm
    end
    module M
      def m
      end
      module N
        def self.nm
        end
        def n
        end
        def a2
        end
      end
    end

    class A
      def self.a1c
      end
      def a1
      end
      def a2
      end
    end

    class B
      include M
      def b
      end
    end
_
  #=> 327
```

```
File.write('file2.rb',
<<_)
    def mm
    end
    module M
      def m
      end
      module N
        def n
        end
        def a2
        end
      end
    end

    module P
      def p
      end
    end

    class A
      include M::N
      def self.a1c
      end
      def a1
      end
    end

    class B
      include P
      def b
      end
    end
_
  #=> 335
```

```
h = find_methods_by_name(files_of_interest)
  #=> {
  #     :imethod=>{
  #       "mm"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>[:main],
  #         "file2.rb"=>[:main]
  #       },
  #       "m"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["module M"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["module M"]
  #       },
  #       "n"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["module M::N"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["module M::N"]
  #       },
  #       "a2"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["module M::N", "class A"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["module M::N"]
  #       },
  #       "a1"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["class A"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["class A"]
  #       },
  #       "b"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["class B"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["class B"]
  #       },
  #       "p"=>{
  #         "file2.rb"=>["module P"]
  #       }
  #     },
  #     :cmethod=>{
  #       "nm"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["module M::N"]
  #       },
  #       "a1c"=>{
  #         "file1.rb"=>["class A"],
  #         "file2.rb"=>["class A"]
  #       }
  #     }
  #   }
```

To eliminate files that appear only once, we can perform an additional step.

```
h.transform_values! { |g| g.reject { |k,v| v.size == 1 && v.values.first.size == 1 } }
```

This removes the instance method `p` and the class method `nm`.